# Unable to load iCloud data into UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to follow an online tutorial to upload the data to `iCloud` and fetch the data from there into my `tableView`. I have followed the tutorial but due to some reasons, I'm not able to load data into my table view. I'm able to successfully upload the data to `iCloud` and query it and after querying I'm able to print it as well. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have written a function to query the database but not sure why the data won't show in the `tableView`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let database = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase

    var notes = [CKRecord]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")

        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(queryDatabase), for: .valueChanged)

        self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        queryDatabase()
    }

    @objc func queryDatabase() {
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Note", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        database.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (records, _) in

            guard let records = records else { return }
            print(records)
            let sortedRecords = records.sorted(by: {$0.creationDate! > $1.creationDate!})

            self.notes = sortedRecords
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
               self.tableView.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return notes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let note = notes[indexPath.row].value(forKey: "content") as! String
        cell.textLabel?.text = note
        return cell
    }
}
```

When I print records I get something like

> [
>   {
>       creatorUserRecordID -> 
>       lastModifiedUserRecordID -> 
>       creationDate -> 2019-04-25 01:26:04 +0000
>       modificationDate -> 2019-04-25 01:26:04 +0000
>       modifiedByDevice -> iPhone XR
>       content -> "HEllo"
>   }, 
>   {
>       creatorUserRecordID -> 
>       lastModifiedUserRecordID -> 
>       creationDate -> 2019-04-25 02:42:03 +0000
>       modificationDate -> 2019-04-25 02:42:03 +0000
>       modifiedByDevice -> iPhone XR
>       content -> "Hi"
>   }]

I wanted to load all the records in my `tableView`.

Comment: Does your code reach `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`?
Also,  you should put `self.notes = sortedRecords` inside of the `DispatchQueue.main.async` closure.

Comment: tableView's dataSource seems not to be set. Try adding `tableView.dataSource = self` in your `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Adding tableview.dataSource =  self worked for me. Thanks @pompopo. But what exactly happened? because seld.tableview.reloadData() should have shown my data right?

Comment: @allanshivji I'm happy that solved your problem. I made answer in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ViewController` has implementation of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, but `tableView` has no `dataSource`.

`tableView.reloadData()` does nothing because the tableView doesn't know what data should be loaded.

dataSource is `The object that acts as the data source of the table view.`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614955-datasource

In this question, adding
`tableView.dataSource = self` in `viewDidLoad` solves the problem.

This code tells tableView to load data from `ViewController`.

This is off topic, though the line `let cell = UITableViewCell()` will make another problem. Search how to reuse UITableViewCell to improve tableView performance.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell

Comment: Thanks, @pompopo. Appreciate your help!